# Rails scope conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

Here are my scopes in the `News` model:

```
scope :category, -> (category_names) { joins(:category).where('categories.name IN (?)', category_names)}  

scope :tag, -> (tag_name) { joins(:tags).where('tags.name = ?', tag_name)}
```

Here's the `GET` request:
`localhost:3000/news?category[]=sit&tag_list=ipsum`

```
[
    {
        "id": 8,
        "tag_list": "ipsum",
        "category": "sit"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "tag_list": "",
        "category": "sit"
    }
]
```

My `index` action:

```
news = News.filter(params.slice(:tag_list, :category, :days_ago))
```

I want to get News which satisfy BOTH of the conditions - only those news should be displayed that have `category="sit"` AND `tag_list="ipsum"`.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply chain the scopes together. In your news controller:

```
News.category(params['categori']).tag(params['tag_list'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply link the scopes as so:

```
News.category(params[:category]).tag(params[:tag_list])
```